# Why is my function called multiple times while I press the button that call the function only one time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a program that generate football fixtures when One button is pressed. Then the fixtures are displayed on the screen. First of all I need to press the button 2 times before I refresh the page so that the fixtures to be generated and displayed. After that sometimes when I press that button I can see multiple lines being generated thing that means that the function is called multiple times on the press of the button, and sometimes it is called only one time and the fixtures are generated only once.

### fixture.php

```
$teams = array("FC FCSB", "AFC Astra Giurgiu", "FC Dinamo 1948", "FC Viitorul 2009", "CSM Politehnica Iasi", "Universitatea Craiova", "FC Botosani", "CFR 1907 Cluj");
$fixPair = new Fixture($teams);
$schedule = $fixPair->getSchedule();
$i = 1;
foreach ($schedule as $rounds) {
    echo "<h5> Etapa " . $i . " </h5>";
    foreach ($rounds as $game) {
        echo "{$game[0]} vs {$game[1]}<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    $i++;
}
echo "<hr>";
```

### JQuery

```
function genereazaEtape() {
            $('.center').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
                var ajaxurl = 'fixture.php',
                data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                    $("#demo1").html(response);
                });
            });
        };
```

### HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="center" onclick="genereazaEtape()"> Generate Fixtures</button>
    <div id="demo1"></div>
```

[I have recorded this so you can understand better.](https://files.fm/u/7r578kc2)

Comment: You need to press the button multiple times because you attach an event listener to the button when you click it. Either just add the listener in your HTML or in your JS, don't do both.

Answer (score 1):

Each time `$('.center').click(...` is executed (in this case when you click on the button) an event listener is added (not replaced), so if you execute 10 times `$('.center').click(...` you'll have 10 listeners. The solution is to add just one time the listener. Example:

```js
$('.center').click(function(e){
                console.log("whatever you want")
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="center">click here</button>
```